# How can I grab the table data for select rows in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to programmatically scrape all the table data from this website
http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&GPType=8.

Ideally this would go row by row. So for example i could say grab all the table data for each row and then have the ability to skip specific rows.

```
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r=requests.get('http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&GPType=8')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')

data = []
info = {}
DataGrid=soup.find('table')
for tr in DataGrid.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    for td in tr.find_all('td')[0]:
            info['Name']=td
    for td in tr.find_all('td')[1]:
            info['City']=td
    for td in tr.find_all('td')[2]:
            td=td.strip().replace(',','')
            info['Phone']=td
    for td in tr.find_all('td')[3]:
            info['more']=td
            data.append(info)
```

I've tried slicing and while it seems to work at the tr level, once i do the loop asking it to find all the table data for each row, i can only get back the entire list of values.

Comment: What actually the `Datagrid` is?

Comment: It's supposed to be the relevant selection of the soup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple tables in the page. If you inspect them all, you discover that the data you want is in the third one. So the code could be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r=requests.get('http://www.virginiaequestrian.com/main.cfm?action=greenpages&GPType=8')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)

tbl = soup.findAll('table')[2]   # Get third table
for tr in tbl.findAll('tr'):     # Get all rows
    for td in tr.findAll('td'):  # Get all cells of row
        if td.p:
            print(td.p.string)
```

Comment: What if i wanted to test this by calling only data for the first row?  for tr in tbl.findAll('tr')[1]: made it break

Comment: @user3590113: Firstly, the element with index 1 is not the first, you should use 0 as index. Secondly, `tbl.findAll('tr')[0]` returns a single element, not a list, so you cannot use it in a `for`. You can use `tbl.findAll('tr')[0:1]` to have a list (iterable) with only the first element.

Comment: How can i return a selected row? Lets day i wanted to show all the values in the third real row?

Comment: How could i grab a row? For instance what if i wanted to full set of values for the third row? how could i get that?

Comment: @user3590113: you can select the third row with: `for tr in tbl.findAll('tr')[2:3]:` and extract the data with: `[td.p for for td in tr.findAll('td') if td.p]`